# Wscript: Where is the logo located?

Tags: vbscript

I don't see any difference when executing each of those two lines of batch file code

```
Wscript Test.vbs
Wscript //Nologo Test.vbs
```

Where is the logo suposed to be located?

Answer (score 6):

Though your question is not clear, I shall tell you the concept of logo/nologo

```
//logo
```

Displays a logo when the script runs under CScript (this is the default setting for WSH). The logo, which appears prior to any of the output from the script, looks like this:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation 1996-2000. All rights reserved.

```
//nologo
```

Prevents display of the logo at run time (by default, the logo is displayed).
The //nologo option is often used for scripts whose output is redirected to a text file. Suppressing the logo ensures that this information does not appear within the text file. This makes it easier to write scripts that parse the information found in the text file or that import the contents of the file to a database, because these scripts do not have to account for the logo.

```
//S
```

Saves the Timeout and Logo options for this user. 
For example, this command ensures that the logo will be suppressed anytime a script runs under CScript:
cscript //nologo //S
You can also modify these settings by right-clicking a script file and then clicking Properties.

Hope you got some benefit from this answer....

Comment: What about the Wscript command? Where is the logo suposed to be located?